# How to update multiple pie charts in one page in D3?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am having multiple pie charts in a single page. How can I update them using a single function? This is what I have done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>
            .chart{
                margin: 10px;
                border: 1px solid;                
                height: 100px;
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chart" id="c1"></div>
        <div class="chart" id="c2"></div>
        <div class="chart" id="c3"></div>
        <input type="button" value="update" id="update"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var data1 = [30, 40, 50],
                    data2 = [20, 50, 10],
                    data3 = [10, 10, 10],
                    data4 = [30, 50, 90],
                    data5 = [30, 10, 20],
                    data6 = [10, 60, 20],
                    t = ["yes", "no", "dont know"];
            var createPie = function(div, p, t) {
                var pwidth = $('.chart').width() - 20,
                        pheight = $('.chart').height() - 10,
                        radius = pheight / 2,
                        outerRadius = radius,
                        innerRadius = 10;
                var color = d3.scale.category10();
                var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
                var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

                var psvg = d3.select(div)
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", pwidth)
                        .attr("height", pheight)
                        .attr("class", "p");
                var arcs = psvg.selectAll("g.arc")
                        .data(pie(p))
                        .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "arc")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
                var paths = arcs.append("path")
                        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                            return color(i);
                        })
                        .attr("d", arc);
                arcs.append("text")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            d.innerRadius = radius;
                            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                        })
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.value;
                        })
                        .style("fill", "#fff");
                var legend = psvg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "legend")
                        .attr("height", 100)
                        .attr("width", 100)
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(-60,10)');
                legend.selectAll('rect')
                        .data(p)
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", pwidth - 65)
                        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                            return i * 20;
                        })
                        .attr("width", 10)
                        .attr("height", 10)
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                            return color(i);
                        });
                legend.selectAll('text')
                        .data(p)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text")
                        .attr("x", pwidth - 52)
                        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                            return i * 20 + 9;
                        })
                        .text(function(d, i) {
                            return t[i];
                        });
            };
            var updatePie = function() {

            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                createPie('#c1', data1, t);
                createPie('#c2', data2, t);
                createPie('#c3', data3, t);
                $("#update").click(function() {
                    updatePie();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have seen the update [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346395). But I can not understand how to pass the data array for the corresponding  pie chart in my update function.

Added a [fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7G68/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple charts with the same layout but different data, you can create a selection of `<svg>` or `<div>` elements, and join them to an array containing all your datasets.  Then both your initialization and update functions are just based on attached data.  So updating is a matter of updating the data and calling the function on each element of your selection of charts.

For your example, that would mean something like:

```
//Initialization
var charts = d3.selectAll("div.chart") //pre-existing elements
      .data([{p:data1, t:t}, {p:data2, t:t}, {p:data3, t:t}])
         //note that I have to include the titles within the data object
         //since I can't pass a separate parameter
      .each(createPie);

//The create pie function is changed to take the standard d3 parameters:
var createPie = function(d, i) {
    var div = this;
    var p = d.p; //or you could just use these as needed
    var t = d.t; // (instead of renaming the variables)

    /* and the rest of your code */
}

//An update function would have the same structure
var updatePie = function(d, i) {
    var arcs = d3.select(this).select("svg.p").selectAll("g.arc")
                 .data( pie(d.p) );

    //assuming the only thing that will change is the numbers,
    //and therefore the size of the pie slices:
    arcs.select("path").attr("d", arc);
}

//The update is called after replacing the data on the charts
charts.data([{p:data4, t:t}, {p:data5, t:t}, {p:data6, t:t}])
      .each(updatePie);
```

You could make the code a little more concise by having your initialization and update functions run on the chart selection as a whole, rather than on each element *(i.e., they would be triggered with a `selection.call(update)` line instead of `selection.each(update)`, and then the called functions would be of the form `function(selection)` not `function(d,i)`)*.  But the above is closer to your existing initialization code.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect, only a small change was required: `var charts = d3.selectAll("div.chart")`.

Answer (score 1):

@AmeliaBR's explanations make good sense (and had I not already spent some time on this, I could have modeled after it). But I was busy working on it...basically, I tried to apply the enter, update, exit pattern to your original code **with minimal changes** and found it difficult to achieve. Without having a whole lot more time to engage on this, I ended up "bypassing" the pattern by taking things down in a draconian way and simply building them back up anew. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7G68/1/) with the results of that.

I am putting it down here as an answer because I did spend some time on it and perhaps it is useful if you are not willing to change the structure of your code much. A snippet of the draconian method below:

```
var updatePie = function (div, p, t) {
    d3.select(div).select("svg").selectAll("g.arc").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning D3. I found the previous answer better, since it takes care of all the charts in my page, instead of individuals. I have made changes in my code accordingly.

Comment: It's a good reminder that, if you can't figure out an update pattern for a complex visualization, you can always just delete and re-run your initial code with the new data.